# JafaFX ListView change Color of single Cells/Items/Rows

Tags: java, listview, javafx, javafx-8, cell

Probably the answer to this question is very simple, so I'm going to try to keep my post so.

**My Problem**
I want the `Text-Color` of different `Cells/Rows/Items` to be customizable through a `JavaFX ColorPicker`. My Code does work, but not really like I want it to.. Everytime a new `Item` is added to the `ListView`, the whole `ListView` changes its `Text-Color` the `Text-Color` chosen for the latest `Item`.

**Here's my code** (Full class linked below, but I don't think it's needed)

```
@FXML
void handleAdd(){   //When add button is clicked

    fontSize = 16.0;

    listView.setCellFactory(cell -> {
        ListCell<String> cel = new ListCell<String>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item != null) {
                    setTextFill(colorPicker.getValue());
                    setFont(Font.font(16));
                    setText(item);
                } else {
                    setText("");
                }
            }
        };
        return cel;
    });


    listView.getItems().add(input.getText()); //input is my TextField

    input.clear();
}
```

[full class](https://hastebin.com/epozisoyiv.java)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a item type for the `ListView` that contains a `ObjectProperty<Color>` in addition to a string

```
private static class ListItem {
    public ListItem(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    private final String text;
    private final ObjectProperty<Color> color = new SimpleObjectProperty(Color.BLACK);
}
```

```
ListView<ListItem> listView;
```

```
listView.setCellFactory(cell -> {
    ListCell<ListItem> cel = new ListCell<ListItem>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(ListItem item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item != null) {
                textFillProperty().bind(item.color);
                setFont(Font.font(16));
                setText(item.text);
            } else {
                setText("");
                textFillProperty().unbind();
                setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
    };
    return cel;
});
```

This way you simply need to set the property to a different value, if you want to change the color, e.g:

```
ListItem selectedItem = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
if (item != null) {
    item.color.set(Color.RED);
}
```

Comment: ... that item wrapping approach again - possible but not the best of ideas: visual logic should be separated from data, always.